# How to turn a dask scalar of type boolean into a boolean expression

Tags: python, dataframe, boolean, dask, delay

I have a long code with many data manipulations in which at the end of it I want to get a boolean expression from comparing two dask series, this is the final part of my code:

```
        scores_for_test_data[f"Healthy Sample Score {exclude_name}"] = np.power(
        (pairwise_test_excluded_sample - healthy_sample_mean_ratio), 2)

    scores_for_test_data[f"Lung Sample Score {exclude_name}"] = np.power(
        (pairwise_test_excluded_sample - lung_sample_mean_ratio), 2)

        scores_for_test_data[f"Sum Healthy Sample Score {exclude_name}"] = scores_for_test_data[
        f"Healthy Sample Score {exclude_name}"].sum()

    scores_for_test_data[f"Sum Lung Sample Score {exclude_name}"] = scores_for_test_data[
        f"Lung Sample Score {exclude_name}"].sum()

        res = scores_for_test_data[f"Sum Healthy Sample Score {exclude_name}"][0] < \
          scores_for_test_data[f"Sum Lung Sample Score {exclude_name}"][0]

    if res.any().compute():
        check += 1
```

(All the variables are dask objects)

My problem is that I'm dealing with a very large dataset, so when I get to the compute() it creates a memory error, res is supposed to be True/False but it is of type 'dask.dataframe.core.Series'

How can I get a boolean expression from this comparison if possible?

scores_for_test_data[f"Sum Healthy Sample Score {exclude_name}"] and scores_for_test_data[f"Sum Lung Sample Score {exclude_name}"] are both dask series with the same value for all of their rows, example:

```
0     2375.861075
1     2375.861075
2     2375.861075
3     2375.861075
4     2375.861075
5     2375.861075
```

That's why I take only the first row from each one in the comparison.

This is what I get:

```
2023-10-22 14:12:56,258 - distributed.worker.memory - WARNING - Unmanaged memory use is high. This may indicate a memory leak or the memory may not be released to the OS; see https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/worker-memory.html#memory-not-released-back-to-the-os for more information. -- Unmanaged memory: 5.70 GiB -- Worker memory limit: 7.98 GiB
2023-10-22 14:12:56,716 - distributed.worker.memory - WARNING - Worker is at 80% memory usage. Pausing worker.  Process memory: 6.40 GiB -- Worker memory limit: 7.98 GiB
2023-10-22 14:12:56,985 - distributed.worker.memory - WARNING - Unmanaged memory use is high. This may indicate a memory leak or the memory may not be released to the OS; see https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/worker-memory.html#memory-not-released-back-to-the-os for more information. -- Unmanaged memory: 5.75 GiB -- Worker memory limit: 7.98 GiB
2023-10-22 14:12:57,109 - distributed.worker.memory - WARNING - Unmanaged memory use is high. This may indicate a memory leak or the memory may not be released to the OS; see https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/worker-memory.html#memory-not-released-back-to-the-os for more information. -- Unmanaged memory: 5.65 GiB -- Worker memory limit: 7.98 GiB
2023-10-22 14:12:57,139 - distributed.worker.memory - WARNING - Unmanaged memory use is high. This may indicate a memory leak or the memory may not be released to the OS; see https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/worker-memory.html#memory-not-released-back-to-the-os for more information. -- Unmanaged memory: 5.69 GiB -- Worker memory limit: 7.98 GiB
2023-10-22 14:12:57,329 - distributed.worker.memory - WARNING - Unmanaged memory use is high. This may indicate a memory leak or the memory may not be released to the OS; see https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/worker-memory.html#memory-not-released-back-to-the-os for more information. -- Unmanaged memory: 5.72 GiB -- Worker memory limit: 7.98 GiB
2023-10-22 14:12:57,329 - distributed.worker.memory - WARNING - Unmanaged memory use is high. This may indicate a memory leak or the memory may not be released to the OS; see https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/worker-memory.html#memory-not-released-back-to-the-os for more information. -- Unmanaged memory: 5.74 GiB -- Worker memory limit: 7.98 GiB
2023-10-22 14:12:57,500 - distributed.worker.memory - WARNING - Worker is at 81% memory usage. Pausing worker.  Process memory: 6.47 GiB -- Worker memory limit: 7.98 GiB
2023-10-22 14:12:57,505 - distributed.nanny.memory - WARNING - Worker tcp://127.0.0.1:55007 (pid=14100) exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting...
2023-10-22 14:12:57,613 - distributed.worker.memory - WARNING - Worker is at 80% memory usage. Pausing worker.  Process memory: 6.39 GiB -- Worker memory limit: 7.98 GiB
2023-10-22 14:12:57,681 - distributed.worker.memory - WARNING - Worker is at 81% memory usage. Pausing worker.  Process memory: 6.49 GiB -- Worker memory limit: 7.98 GiB
2023-10-22 14:12:57,686 - distributed.worker.memory - WARNING - Unmanaged memory use is high. This may indicate a memory leak or the memory may not be released to the OS; see https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/worker-memory.html#memory-not-released-back-to-the-os for more information. -- Unmanaged memory: 5.69 GiB -- Worker memory limit: 7.98 GiB
2023-10-22 14:12:57,784 - distributed.worker.memory - WARNING - Unmanaged memory use is high. This may indicate a memory leak or the memory may not be released to the OS; see https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/worker-memory.html#memory-not-released-back-to-the-os for more information. -- Unmanaged memory: 5.78 GiB -- Worker memory limit: 7.98 GiB
2023-10-22 14:12:57,872 - distributed.worker.memory - WARNING - Worker is at 81% memory usage. Pausing worker.  Process memory: 6.52 GiB -- Worker memory limit: 7.98 GiB
2023-10-22 14:12:57,877 - distributed.worker.memory - WARNING - Worker is at 81% memory usage. Pausing worker.  Process memory: 6.47 GiB -- Worker memory limit: 7.98 GiB
2023-10-22 14:12:58,034 - distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
2023-10-22 14:12:58,218 - distributed.worker.memory - WARNING - Worker is at 81% memory usage. Pausing worker.  Process memory: 6.48 GiB -- Worker memory limit: 7.98 GiB
2023-10-22 14:12:58,276 - distributed.nanny.memory - WARNING - Worker tcp://127.0.0.1:54993 (pid=3008) exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting...
2023-10-22 14:12:58,357 - distributed.worker.memory - WARNING - Worker is at 81% memory usage. Pausing worker.  Process memory: 6.52 GiB -- Worker memory limit: 7.98 GiB
2023-10-22 14:12:58,405 - distributed.nanny.memory - WARNING - Worker tcp://127.0.0.1:54986 (pid=9212) exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting...
2023-10-22 14:12:58,443 - distributed.nanny.memory - WARNING - Worker tcp://127.0.0.1:55004 (pid=4788) exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting...
2023-10-22 14:12:58,568 - distributed.nanny.memory - WARNING - Worker tcp://127.0.0.1:55001 (pid=7332) exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting...
2023-10-22 14:12:58,682 - distributed.nanny.memory - WARNING - Worker tcp://127.0.0.1:54989 (pid=12900) exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting...
2023-10-22 14:12:58,956 - distributed.nanny.memory - WARNING - Worker tcp://127.0.0.1:54992 (pid=8280) exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting...
2023-10-22 14:12:58,983 - distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
2023-10-22 14:12:59,139 - distributed.nanny.memory - WARNING - Worker tcp://127.0.0.1:54998 (pid=3868) exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting...
2023-10-22 14:12:59,239 - distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
2023-10-22 14:12:59,348 - distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
2023-10-22 14:12:59,515 - distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
2023-10-22 14:12:59,718 - distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
2023-10-22 14:13:00,020 - distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
2023-10-22 14:13:00,363 - distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
2023-10-22 14:13:19,717 - distributed.worker.memory - WARNING - Unmanaged memory use is high. This may indicate a memory leak or the memory may not be released to the OS; see https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/worker-memory.html#memory-not-released-back-to-the-os for more information. -- Unmanaged memory: 5.78 GiB -- Worker memory limit: 7.98 GiB
```

Please can someone help

Comment: I don't think the problem comes from this comparison and the final res object. res would be a series with only one item, so should be pretty small. Memory error probably comes from operations before the comparison.

Comment: @GuillaumeEB yes I have many operations I've performed before, how can I get my final result after all of these operations? from my understanding once you get to a final small data dask can run the compute command and give the result, but I can't seem to make that work in my code...

Comment: Could you show us the stack trace you're getting? Dask is lazy and tries to optimize the computations it does to get only the results it needs, but it is not always feasible, and if you need at some point to compute a big collection, you can easily run into memory errors.

Comment: @GuillaumeEB Thank you for your reply, I added it to my question

Comment: You don't have a Python error stack trace? The logs are telling one of your operation is loading too much data into memory, but it's impossible to tell which one. Maybe you should try to perform operations part by part in order to understand where it's failing, or use the Dask Dashboard to monitor the execution.

Comment: @GuillaumeEB Eventually I get this error: 
raise CommClosedError(reason)
distributed.comm.core.CommClosedError: Address removed.